# Decode HTML from XML with NewLine

Tags: iphone, new-operator, line, decoding

First I parse XML and retrieve this:

```
&#60;p&#62;&#60;strong&#62;Berns Salonger &#45; the City&#39;s
```

The I decode it with MWFeedParser (*stringByDecodingHTMLEntities*) and retrieve this:

```
<p><strong>Berns Salonger - the City's Ideal Meeting Place
```

Note that this is only one line of many many lines which includes alot of 
 tags.

Then I replace 
 with \n and the console writes out the text with new lines. Everything is great except that all the other HTML tags is still there.

So I then run *stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText* and all HTML tags dissapears. **But** also my replaced new lines.

How can I decode HTML without and at the same time replace 
 with \n to print out a nice formatted text in a *UITextView*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing `<br>` with `\n`, try replacing it with an HTML entity for newline: `&#10;`. Then, when you call `stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText`, it will convert the entity to an actual newline character.

Comment: If I want to replace <p> and </p>? I can't fint the HTML entity for that. I thought it was &para; but it wasn't.

Comment: I tried with:
 contentText = [contentText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@"&#60;p&#62;"];
 contentText = [contentText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@"&#60;&#47;p&#62;"];

But that didn't work either.

Comment: Use the same entity for <p>: &#10; Maybe use two of them for double spacing.